# XSLT - How to get the first value in a repeating Tag - So simple but not that simple

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

I have an XML where I am getting various phone types and their values. The XML has more than one value for the same phone type (ex, one can have two mobile phone numbers). I have to get the first value using XSLT, no matter how many numbers it has. Its a real simple ask but I am breaking my head on this. Here is the example XML, I want the mobile number with all 2s -

```
<Work_Phone>
  <Work_Phones_group>
    <WorkphoneType wd:Descriptor="Fax">
      <ID wd:type="Device">Fax</wd:ID>
    </WorkphoneType>
    <WorkphoneNumber>111-111-1111</wd:WorkphoneNumber>
  </Work_Phones_group>
  <Work_Phones_group>
    <WorkphoneType wd:Descriptor="Mobile">
      <ID wd:type="Device">Mobile</wd:ID>
    </WorkphoneType>
    <WorkphoneNumber>222-222-2222</wd:WorkphoneNumber>
  </Work_Phones_group>
  <Work_Phones_group>
    <WorkphoneType wd:Descriptor="Mobile">
      <ID wd:type="Device">Mobile</wd:ID>
    </WorkphoneType>
    <WorkphoneNumber>333-333-3333</wd:WorkphoneNumber>
  </Work_Phones_group>
</Work_Phone>
```

Output value required - 222-222-2222

Unfortunately, there is no key or any other field that differentiates two mobile number entries. Do you have any suggestions or solutions for this? Any pointer is appreciated.

Comment: Please post a **well-formed** example of the XML input, and also show the expected output.

Comment: @michael.hor257k - added the output for clarity. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

Your XML is not *well-formed*. I changed some namespace prefixes to make it *well-formed* which removes some inconsistencies:

```
<Work_Phone xmlns:wd="http://some.wd.ns">
    <Work_Phones_group>
        <WorkphoneType wd:Descriptor="Fax">
            <wd:ID wd:type="Device">Fax</wd:ID>
        </WorkphoneType>
        <wd:WorkphoneNumber>111-111-1111</wd:WorkphoneNumber>
    </Work_Phones_group>
    <Work_Phones_group>
        <WorkphoneType wd:Descriptor="Mobile">
            <wd:ID wd:type="Device">Mobile</wd:ID>
        </WorkphoneType>
        <wd:WorkphoneNumber>222-222-2222</wd:WorkphoneNumber>
    </Work_Phones_group>
    <Work_Phones_group>
        <WorkphoneType wd:Descriptor="Mobile">
            <wd:ID wd:type="Device">Mobile</wd:ID>
        </WorkphoneType>
        <wd:WorkphoneNumber>333-333-3333</wd:WorkphoneNumber>
    </Work_Phones_group>
</Work_Phone>
```

Now, to get the desired value of `222-222-2222`, use this XPath-1.0 expression

```
/Work_Phone/Work_Phones_group[WorkphoneType/@wd:Descriptor='Mobile'][1]/wd:WorkphoneNumber
```

or customize this template to get the values you really want

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="Work_Phone/Work_Phones_group[WorkphoneType/@wd:Descriptor='Mobile'][1]">
        <xsl:value-of select="wd:WorkphoneNumber" />
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks @zx485 -- Yes i copied the skeleton of XML and modified it to remove some unwanted values and tags and in doing so i broke it. Thanks a ton. ForLoop with [1] will get me what i want.